# How can I create an external table in HIVE from HDFS file that contains a JSON array?

Tags: arrays, json, hive, hdfs

My json looks like this:

```
  [
  {
  "blocked": 1,
  "object": {
  "ip": "abc",
  "src_ip": "abc",
  "lan_initiated": true,
  "detection": "abc",
  "src_port": ,
  "src_mac": "abc",
  "dst_mac": "abc",
  "dst_ip": "abc",
  "dst_port": "abc"
},
"object_type": "url",
"threat": "",
"threat_type": "abc",
"device_id": "abc",
"app_id": "abc",
"user_id": "abc",
"timestamp": 1520268249657,
"date": {
  "$date": "Mon Mar 05 2018 16:44:09 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
},
"expire": {
  "$date": "Fri May 04 2018 16:44:09 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
},
"_id": "abc"
  }
]
```

I have tried:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table_name`(
  reports array<struct<
  user_id: string ,
  device_id: string ,
  app_id: string ,
  blocked: string ,
  object: struct<ip:string,src_ip:string,lan_initiated:string,detection:string,src_port:string,src_mac:string,dst_mac:string,dstp_ip:string,dst_port:string> ,
  object_type: string ,
  threat: string ,
  threat_type: string ,
  servertime:string,
  date_t: struct<dat:string>,
  expire: struct<dat:string>,
  id: string >>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'ignore.malformed.json'='false','mapping.dat'='$date', 'mapping.servertime'='timestamp','mapping.date'='date_t','mapping._id'='id')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'abc'
```

and after that

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
LATERAL VIEW outer explode(reports) exploded_table as rep;
```

but i get: Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE -  killed/failed due to:null.

I have read that because the JSON starts with '[' it cannot be parsed. Any ideas? The structure of the json must be changed?

Comment: Can you try with '{"reports": [...your data...]}`?

Comment: @Bala , thank you for your question, I can't modify the structure of the json files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have made mistake in specifying location
In the code, you have mentioned

```
LOCATION
  'abc'
```

`LOCATION` is expected to be a folder in which your `JSON` file should be present. You can have any name for the `JSON` file.

You also need to make sure that the [JSON-Serde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) jar is there in the classpath. If not, use below command before trying to create the table.

```
hive> add jar /path/to/<json-serde-jar>;
```